# Query regarding a java script code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following piece of code which i have got from internet.
I am not able to understand how does this works. What is 'rules' and 'messages'  in the code.

Is it a structure or a switch.
Please help me to understand.

```
$(function()
    {
        $('<i class="icon-ok"></i><i class="icon-remove"></i>').appendTo($('#form section'));

        $("#form").validate(
        {
            // Rules for form validation
            rules:
            {
                rtype:
                {
                    required: true
                },
                trn:
                {
                    required: true
                },
                ltype:
                {
                    required: true
                },
                date:
                {
                    required: true
                },
            },

            // Messages for form validation
            messages:
            {
                rtype:
                {
                    required: 'Please enter your load request type'
                },
                date:
                {
                    required: 'Please enter Due date provided ',
                    date: 'Please enter a realistic date'
                },
                ltype:
                {
                    required: 'Please select your load type'
                },
                trn:
                {
                    required: 'Please enter your transaction'
                },
            },                  

            // Do not change code below
            errorPlacement: function(error, element)
            {
                error.appendTo(element.parent());
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

*Rules* are the restrictions on the form input fields and *Messages* are the error messages that would show up on corresponding error.

The validation plugin that you have included in your code uses these objects to work accordingly.

More Info: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/